# TDA2822D speaker connection issue

Tags: circuit-design

[image: Application circuit]

This is the [circuit](https://www.st.com/en/audio-ics/tda2822d.html) from the datasheet TDA2822D.

I have a question regarding the connections near the 32/16 ohm headphone. Why the two terminals of the speakers are connected together to the ground. I tried to draw the circuit, do I connect the pin1 and pin2 to the ground?

[image: my circuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ground connection would be that each speaker element in the headphones are connected to GND. In the picture of your ciruit you have shorted Left and Right to GND so there would be no sound.

Then I don't know whether you want the speaker element there or headphones, but TDA2822D can be wired for either stereo or mono to satisfy both setups.

Here's a page describing the subject in depth:
[Headphone Jacks and Plugs: Everything You Need to Know](https://www.headphonesty.com/2019/04/headphone-jacks-plugs-explained/)

Especially **Different Plug Conductor Configurations**

Comment: I am still confused about "each speaker element in the headphones are connected to GND". In my diagram, will it work if I just remove the ground connection under U2?

If I connect each speaker element in the headphones to GND, I think I understand it as "connect two headphone terminals to ground", which will short the circuit. This is the part that I confused of.

Comment: If you open a headphone plug or cable, you will see there are 3 connections / wires. 2 of them are Left and Right signal, and the third is the return to GND. If there's no return path the elements would need to be in serial, which means you don't get stereo but mono. If mono is ok with you, the amplifier can be configured that way too.

Answer (score 2):

The schematic has been edited to clarify your doubt.

[image]